# Making a new style using a existing one through memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm having some issues while trying to create a new style based on another preexistent in memoir.

After consulting some other threads on this issue, [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64222/creating-a-specific-chapter-style-using-memoir) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193372/how-to-create-such-a-chapter-style), I've tried the following code, using a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{test}{%
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
\normalfont\small\bfseries\flushright}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
\normalfont\large\bfseries\flushright}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\flushright\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
}

\chapterstyle{test}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

How can I make the *Chapter* and the number of the chapter together aligned to the right? Also, can I do [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246013/how-can-i-reduce-the-space-above-the-title-of-a-single-chapter) to all chapter titles instead of doing it locally?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) you should use `\raggedleft` here, not `\flushright` as `\flushright` is actually an environment, so does more than you need here. Replace the two first `\flushright` with `\raggedleft` and remove the last one as you already set it in the font setting. To reduce the spacing above either use `\setlength{\beforechapskip}{some value}` or redefine `\chapterheadstart` to do nothing. Note you have only changed the `\chapnumfont`, you probably also want to change `\chapternamefont`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work.

You should use `\raggedleft` here, not `\flushright` as `\flushright` is actually start of an  environment, so does more than you need here. Replace the two first `\flushright` with `\raggedleft` and remove the last one as you already set it in the font setting. To reduce the spacing above either use `\setlength{\beforechapskip}{some value}` or redefine `\chapterheadstart` to do nothing. Note you have only changed the `\chapnumfont`, you probably also want to change `\chapternamefont`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{test}{%
  \chapterstyle{bianchi}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
    \normalfont\small\bfseries\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\small\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
  \setlength\beforechapskip{0pt} % not the same as no space above
                                % because of \vspace* internally
}

\chapterstyle{test}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% note to show where the text block is
%\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{showlocs}


\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed working, although I'm going to ask a bit more on this: (1) Can I define the \setlength\beforechapskip{0pt} as \setlength\beforechapskip{-'somevalue'pt}? (2) Also, the space after the chapter title can be altered with \setlength\afterhapskip? (3) Can I reduce the space of the lines holding the chapter title?
Thank you!

Comment: Just altered the default style from bianchi to lyhne and it worked. \before and afterhapskip do work, haven't tried negative numbers though.

Comment: @TiagoCorreia you generally should not need negative values as you are not adding to the existing lengths (unless you're using `\addtolength`)

Comment: Ok, understood. Keeping these values to 0 will respect the document instated in the document, right? If so, will keep them that way. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: 'respect the margins instated in the document' and not 'respect the document instated in the document'...